# How do I fill a string column using a set in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge dataset with two specific columns for Sales Person and Manager. I want to make a new column which assigns sales person name on different basis.

So lets say that Under Manager John, I have 4 executives - A, B, C, D

I want to replace the existing sales person under John  with the executives A, B, C and D in a sequence.

Here is what I want to do -

Input-

| ID | SalesPerson | Sales Manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AM12 | Oliver | Bren |
| AM21 | Athreyu | John |
| AM31 | Margarita | Fer |
| AM41 | Jenny | Fer |
| AM66 | Omar | John |
| AM81 | Michael | Nati |
| AM77 | Orlan | John |
| AM87 | Erika | Nateran |
| AM27 | Jesus | John |
| AM69 | Randy | John |

Output -

| ID | SalesPerson | Sales Manager | SalesPerson_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AM12 | Oliver | Bren | oliver |
| AM21 | Athreyu | John | A |
| AM31 | Margarita | Fer | Margarita |
| AM41 | Jenny | Fer | Jenny |
| AM66 | Omar | John | B |
| AM81 | Michael | Nati | Michael |
| AM77 | Orlan | John | C |
| AM87 | Erika | Nateran | Nateran |
| AM27 | Jesus | John | D |
| AM69 | Randy | John | A |

Comment: Why is Randy coded as A? shouldn't he be E ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `cumcount` and `.map`

first we need to build up a dictionary that repeats `ABCD` in multiple of fours.

i.e `{0 : 'A', 1 : 'B', 2 : 'C', 3 : 'D', 4 : 'A'}`

we can do this with a helper function and some handy modules from the itertools library.

```
from itertools import cycle, zip_longest, islice
from string import ascii_uppercase
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def repeatlist(it, count):
    return islice(cycle(it), count)

mapper = dict(zip_longest(range(50), repeatlist(ascii_uppercase[:4],50)))


df['SalesPersonNew'] = np.where(
df['Sales Manager'].eq('John'),
         df.groupby('Sales Manager')['SalesPerson'].cumcount().map(mapper),
         df['SalesPerson'])

print(df)

  ID SalesPerson Sales Manager SalesPersonNew
0  AM12      Oliver          Bren         Oliver
1  AM21     Athreyu          John              A
2  AM31   Margarita           Fer      Margarita
3  AM41       Jenny           Fer          Jenny
4  AM66        Omar          John              B
5  AM81     Michael          Nati        Michael
6  AM77       Orlan          John              C
7  AM87       Erika       Nateran          Erika
8  AM27       Jesus          John              D
9  AM69       Randy          John              A
```

Comment: very neat use of `islice` + `cycle`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma can't take the credit for it, saw someone else suggest it on here ages and and kept it in my gist :) or maybe it was in FluentPython

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your dataframe is the variable `df`.

First you need to create the new column on your dataframe, which you can initiate with the values already present in the `SalesPerson` column.

```
df["SalesPerson_new"] = df["SalesPerson"]
```

Then you can make a view of your dataframe to select the rows where the value of `Sales Manager` is `John`, and use that to update the `SalesPerson_new` column.

```
number_of_rows = len(df.loc[df["Sales Manager"] == "John", :])
df.loc[df["Sales Manager"] == "John", :] = ["A", "B", "C", "D"][:number_of_rows]
```

It is important to note that this will work only if the list `["A", "B", "C", "D"]` has a length equal or larger than the number of rows in the `filtered_df`

Comment: Hi @Jundiaius, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, my length of list is less than the  rows in the filtered data. Any idea how we can do it in this scenario? Thanks